# Excel using COUNTIF() to find a matches on a table returns #VALUE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using COUNTIF() on a formula to find matches from some input strings into a table, but for some reason the first entry is not working properly and returning #VALUE unless I use a referenced cell as input.

This is the whole formula with the input string that returns the #VALUE ouput:

`=COUNTIF(CALC_SiteSize,$A$2:$A$19)`

[Matches using named function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N2II.png)

Where:

`CALC_SiteSize=SWITCH(SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(INPUT_AP_NAME)>0)),0,"",1,"Isolated",2,"Small",5,"Regional",10,"Big")`

[Reference cell with result from CALC_SiteSize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LFnG.png)

But if I use whatever cell where I get the result from "CALC_SiteSize" as reference input, it works:

`=COUNTIF($C$2,$A$2:$A$19)`

[Matches using reference cell where named function returns value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH8oX.png)

Comment: Then check the output from the named function.

Comment: That's because `CALC_SiteSize` resolves to a string, and the first argument for `COUNTIF` must be a range object.  Hence the error.

Comment: As @Domenic stated, first argument for COUNTIF must be range. Anyway, you counting "one to many", so =N(CALC_SiteSize=$A$2:$A$19) should give same result except for asterisk symbol

Comment: Thanks @user11222393 for the hint (and also Domenic), this is working like a charm using 'N' which I have never seen before, except for asterisk, but I would look into another way of solving the "*" match

Comment: If using Office 365, this might work =N(BYROW(A2:A19,LAMBDA(x,OR(CALC_SiteSize=x,"*"=x))))

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used the countif in wrong way.

first argument should be a 'range'.
I am not sure if you are using a 'range' or a value.

please check this point once.

Thanks
Have a good day!

Comment: I'm using countif to match differents columns so the result would be a single match (all 1's) and that result used inside an index+match returning the value that I want. I don't know how this method is called, but it works.


`=INDEX(REF_rf_profile_column,
MATCH(1,
COUNTIF(CALC_SiteSize,REF_rf_site_size_column)*
COUNTIF(IN_site_type,"*"&REF_rf_site_type_column&"*")*
COUNTIF(IN_wan_router,"*"&REF_meraki_column&"*")*
COUNTIF(IN_ssid_iot_bool,REF_rf_iot_column)*
COUNTIF(IN_ssid_voice_bool,REF_rf_voice_column),0))'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).